# Use of This in Java

Tags: java

How does the increment method calling work in the following code:

```
public class Leaf {

  int i = 0;
  Leaf increment(){
    i++;
    return this;
  }
  void print(){
    System.out.println("i = "+ i);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Leaf x = new Leaf();
    x.increment().increment().increment().print();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is an example of [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

By returning `this`, subsequent calls to instance methods of the original object instance can be made in a chain.

Each call to `increment()` increases the value of `i` by 1, since the call is acting on the original object instance.

Finally, `print()` is called on the original object instance to output the value of `i`.

Comment: @AbdulRahman To add on to this answer:  If you hear the term 'fluent interfaces,'  this is the technique that is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code we're trying to run:

```
x.increment().increment().increment().print();
```

And here's the method we have:

```
Leaf increment() {
    i++;
    return this;
}
```

It's called method chaining. Let's see what'd happen if we don't `return this`:

```
void increment() {
    i++;
}
```

And the code would look like this:

```
x.increment();
x.increment();
x.increment();
x.print();
```

See? It's just simpler to return the object and chain the method calls.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Stupid typo :P

Answer (score 0):

It does increment by one object field `int i` and then returns reference to the object for which `increment()` method has been invoked, thus you can invoke `increment()` again after dot. for the same leaf.